# How to authorise ADFS users from PHP

Tags: php, azure, adfs, adfs2.0

I need to allow adfs user to login in php based application.We can integrate SimpleSAMLphp for this purpose but all we need to make Relay Trust Connection through SAML metadata on ADFS server but we can't do that as client don't allow for this. I didn't found any way to authenticate ADFS user by any single api that we pass user credentials and will get ADFS response is user authorised or not?

Even I don't need any user details from ADFS server only to check weather the user is valid or not?

Answer (score 1):

Need more detail.

This works no problem.

Application --> simpleSAMLphp --> ADFS

What does not work?

SAML does "pass user credentials and will get ADFS response is user **authenticated** or not".

You need to use roles in the SAML assertions to handle authorisation.

Comment: thanks. Problem is we can’t get adfs server to create new relay trust connection for simpleSAML. So can we use simpleSAMLphp without configuration on adsf?  As I know we can’t. We have adfs server details, Federation meta XML.  Not found any way that can  authenticate adfs user by this.

Comment: http://www.lewisroberts.com/2015/09/06/integrating-simplesamlphp-with-adfs-2012r2/

Comment: I have checked this before, here as well we need to add simpleSAML meta to adfs. As I states earlier we don’t have access to adfs server, so can’t create any new relay. That’s the problem is there any other way to do so?

Comment: Normally you send the simpleSAMLphp metadata to the ADFS admin. and they configure it for you.

Comment: we have 5-6 applications on same server, so can we authenticate with single simpleSAMLphp library or do we need to do the same process for all sites. All sites are under subdomain. Can we achieve this by remote hosted metadata?

Comment: Each application needs code to integrate with simpleSAMLphp but you only need one simpleSAMLphp instance.

Comment: I have implemented above and working fine. Now to support on mobile we have implemented a way on that we are getting JWT token from ADFS now can you please help how can we validate that token?